# Is AES 256 CBC Crypto (Cipher) logic is there in Kotlin Multi Platform (KMM)?

Tags: ios, kmm

I found AES encryption logic in Kotlin by using JavaX libraries. Since it's specific to java (Android) so it's not executing for iOS.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do see no question in your post. As noticed in the main website of kotlin: "*You only need to write platform-specific code where it’s necessary, for example to implement a native UI or when working with platform-specific APIs.*". And yes, the encryption is implemented in platform specific APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [krypto](https://github.com/korlibs/korge/tree/main/krypto) or [libsodum wrapper](https://github.com/ionspin/kotlin-multiplatform-libsodium) libraries.

For example, with krypto library you can easily implement AES CBC in commanMain module by using these functions:

```
implementation("com.soywiz.korlibs.krypto:krypto:${Version.krypto}")



AES.encryptAesEcb(dataByteArray, keyByteArray, Padding.NoPadding)
AES.decryptAesEcb(dataByteArray, keyByteArray, Padding.ANSIX923Padding)
```